# Pandas column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the fastest way to convert a pandas column to one concatenated string?

For example, if `df['col1']` contained the below:

```
col1
word1
word2
word3
```

What is the ideal way to return `'word1 word2 word3'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1]** Use `str.cat`

```
In [3761]: df.col1.str.cat(sep=' ')
Out[3761]: 'word1 word2 word3'
```

**Option 2]** Use `join`

```
In [3763]: ' '.join(df.col1)
Out[3763]: 'word1 word2 word3'
```

Instead use `list` which is faster in this case.

```
In [3794]: ' '.join(df.col1.values.tolist())
Out[3794]: 'word1 word2 word3'

In [3795]: df.col1.values.tolist()
Out[3795]: ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

---

**Timings**

*Mid-size*

```
In [3769]: df.shape
Out[3769]: (30000, 1)

In [3770]: %timeit df.col1.str.cat(sep=' ')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop

In [3771]: %timeit ' '.join(df.col1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 796 µs per loop

In [3788]: %timeit ' '.join(df.col1.values.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 492 µs per loop
```

*Large-size*

```
In [3774]: df.shape
Out[3774]: (300000, 1)

In [3775]: %timeit df.col1.str.cat(sep=' ')
10 loops, best of 3: 29.7 ms per loop

In [3776]: %timeit ' '.join(df.col1)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.22 ms per loop

In [3791]: %timeit ' '.join(df.col1.values.tolist())
100 loops, best of 3: 6.69 ms per loop
```

---

- `' '.join(df.col1.values.tolist())` is much faster than `df.col1.str.cat(sep=' ')`